# How do make an SSL Connection from a Kong serverless function using a client certificate

Tags: ssl, lua, openresty, kong

I'm trying to create a serverless function for Kong for authentication purposes.  I'm required to use a client certificate to authenticate with the remote service that we have to use.  I can't seem to get this working and there appears to be no clear documentation on how to do this.  I've tried pintsized/lua-resty-http, ngx.socket.tcp(), and luacurl (failed to build) without success.  I'm using the newest version of Kong in an Alpine Linux container in case that matters.

What is the best way to do this?  Right now I'm considering simply calling curl from within Lua as I know that works, but I was hoping for a better solution that I can do with just Lua/OpenResty.

Thanks.

UPDATE: I just wanted to add, just in case it helps, that I'm already building a new image based on the official Kong one as I had to modify the nginx configuration templates, so installing new software into the container is not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

All,

Apologies for the ugly code, but it looks like a found an answer that works:

```
require("socket")
local currUrl= "https://some.url/"
local https = require("ssl.https")
local ltn12 = require("ltn12")
local chunks = {}
local body, code, headers, status = https.request{
    mode = "client",
    url = currUrl,
    protocol = "tlsv1_2",
    certificate = "/certs/bundle.crt",
    key = "/certs/bundle.key",
    verify = "none",
    sink = ltn12.sink.table(chunks),
}
```

If someone has a better answer, I'd appreciate it, but it's hard to complain about this one.  The main issue is that while this works for a GET request, I'll be wanting to do POSTs to a service in a future and I have no idea how to do it using similar code.  I'd like one libary/API that can do any type of REST request.

This blog got me on the right track: http://notebook.kulchenko.com/programming/https-ssl-calls-with-lua-and-luasec

Comment: Lua socker library is not good choice for OpenResty because of blocking socket API.